# I don't know why my npm have no respond that is var uc = require('upper-case');

Tags: javascript, npm

i just following the w3school npm tutorial, but it no respond.

i am using macbook pro 2019, and using Vs code to program it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id=uc></p>
        <script>
            var uc = require('upper-case');
            document.getElementById('uc').innerHTML = uc("asdjkad");
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

xxx and yyy is a filter of me and my computer name

```
(base) xxx:~ yyy$ npm ls -g
/Users/yyy/.npm-global/lib
├─┬ increase-memory-limit@1.0.7
│ └─┬ glob@7.1.4
│   ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
│   ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
│   │ ├── once@1.4.0 deduped
│   │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
│   ├── inherits@2.0.4
│   ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4
│   │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.11
│   │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0
│   │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
│   ├─┬ once@1.4.0
│   │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 deduped
│   └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
├── jquery@3.4.1
└── upper-case@1.1.3
```

i expect the html/javascript can run the upper-case node

Answer (score 2):

`require` isn't a built-in part of JavaScript or the browser environment. It's a built-in part of the Node.js (non-browser) environment, and a function provided by various libraries and bundlers (such as Webpack and Browserify).

If you want to use an `npm` module in browser-hosted code, you have to either:

1. Include it via `script` tag, provided it doesn't rely on any other modules (unlikely), or
2. Use a bundler that understands `require` syntax and can bundle up the module code into a browser-compatible script.